# Dojo FilteringSelect behavior on page scroll

Tags: javascript, dojo

When I open Dojo `filteringSelect` and scroll page, content of `filteringSelect` scrolls together with the page. I can not understand why it works such way, and how can I fix it.

Please suggest some ideas.

Comment: Create a fiddle and explain the expected behaviour.

Comment: Now it works like on picture http://i.imgur.com/30qmYLJ.png

Comment: I want it to hide when page is scrolling

Comment: Which version do you use? I've tried to simulate the problem, but I didn't succeed and I get the expected result. http://jsfiddle.net/GuyT/ua5qzrvw/

Comment: This was fixed in 1.9, I think. The problem is that the dropdown is (actually a popup) directly under <body/>, but the FilteringSelect may be in a sub element which does the actual scrolling. Here's a variant of GuyT's fiddle that demonstrates it: http://jsfiddle.net/ua5qzrvw/1/ If you switch to 1.9 or 1.10 in the sidebar, you'll see that the dropdown follows the scrolling.

Comment: @Frode You are correct. I can confirm it after checking out the fiddle.